# Variable not splitting in R Decision Tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm using the party package in R to build a decision tree that has gender as one of my variables (1 for male, 2 for female, 99 for unknown) and my tree output only shows one node (basically not splitting into female or male).  Below is the code that I'm using.  I want to be able to see if my target variable (income) varies by gender.

```
library(party)
tree <- ctree(Mean_Incomef~Gender, data = mdftrain,controls = ctree_control(mincriterion=0.95,minsplit=20))
tree
plot(tree)
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possibly, in your data, there is no significant difference in income based on gender. Try `aggregate(Mean_Incomef~Gender, data=mdftrain, FUN=mean)`